# Moving dynamically created images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been learning JavaScript for about 2 months and I'm trying to make sort of a dumbed down version of Space Invaders. Basically, there's a spaceship that moves left and right at the bottom of the `div` that contains the game. Asteroids come from the top and you have to shoot at them by hitting the spacebar. I managed to get the bullets to spawn correctly, but I can't get them to move upwards slowly.

This is what I've got for spawning the bullets:

```
  function spawnBullet(evento) {
        if (evento.charCode==32) {
            newBullet=document.createElement("img");
            newBullet.classList.add("bullet");
            newBullet.setAttribute("src", "images/bullet.png");
            newBullet.setAttribute("style", "left: "+parseInt(parseInt(document.getElementById("spaceship").style.left)+15)+"px");
            document.getElementById("spaceWrap").appendChild(newBullet);
            bullets.push(newBullet);
        }
    }
```

Where `bullets` is basically intended to be an array of objects, containing every bullet currently on screen, and the parameter `evento` is passed by `onkeypress="event"` on the container `div`.

Here is the CSS for the `bullets` class:

```
.bullet {
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    display: block;
}
```

Now for the movement:

```
function moveBulletsTimer() {
    bulletTimer=setInterval(moveBullets, 100);
}

function moveBullets() {
    for (var i=0; i<=bullets.length-1; i++) {
        if (bullets[i].style.top<=document.getElementById("gameWindow").style.height)
            bullets[i].style.top=parseInt(bullets[i].style.top)-10+'px';
        else {
            bullets[i].remove();
            bullets.pop(bullets[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

`moveBulletsTimer()` is started when the player clicks the START button.

I think I'm having a problem somewhere with setInterval, because the `top` property never changes.

I could host the whole HTML/CSS/JS files somewhere because copying them here would be crazy, they're 70+ lines each and currently a very WIP mess.

Comment: Try this instead of setInterval http://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/

Comment: Check out https://jsfiddle.net for an easy way to host a demo for this.

Comment: consider using `setTimer()` instead of `setInterval()`. Each time `moveBullets()` is called, make another call to`setTimer()` to handle the next animation frame. This will avoid the problem that @JonHerbert identifies in his code reference.